# Making API Calls

Tags: javascript

Am trying to make api calls to three apis and my code is as follows in my server. I get lat and lon from geoNames api call and used that lat and lon to get weather data from weatherbit, but it gives the error that is at the bottom of this post:

```
    const { date, city } = req.body;
  // Call to the geonames API
    const geoNames = `http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON? 
    q=${city}&maxRows=1&username=${process.env.USERNAME}`;
    console.log(`${process.env.USERNAME}`)
    fetch(geoNames)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      // getting latitude and longitude
      const lat = json.geonames[0].lat;
      const lng = json.geonames[0].lng;
      console.log(geoNames)
      console.log(lat)
      console.log(lng)

      // Call to the weatherbit API
      const weatherBit = 
      `https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/forecast/daily?l 
lat=${lat}&lon=${lng}&key=${process.env.WEATHERKEY},${date}`;
      console.log(`${process.env.WEATHERKEY}`)
      fetch(weatherBit)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => { 
            console.log(json);
          const city = res.json.data[0].city_name;
          const icon = res.json.data[0].weather.icon;
          const description = res.json.data[0].weather.description;
          const tempHigh = res.json.data[0].max_temp;
          const tempLow = res.json.data[0].min_temp;
            
          // Call to the pixabay API
          const pixaBay = `https://pixabay.com/api/?key=${process.env.PIXAKEY}&q=${city}&image_type=photo`;
          fetch(pixaBay)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(json)
              const img = json.hits[0].webformatURL;
              const pixObj = { city: city, icon: icon, description: description, tempHigh: tempHigh, tempLow: tempLow, img: img };
              res.send(pixObj);
              console.log(pixObj)
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I get the following errors when I run the code:

http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=Cancun&maxRows=1&username=kamara.moses
21.17429
-86.84656
cda6df51d9a24b8c9d54b830f4eadb51
{ error: 'API key not valid, or not yet activated.' }
(node:69146) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Error is self-explanatory, you have provided invalid API-key in your requests.

Comment: I tried out the key and it is valid and correct. Am assuming the way I wrote the code might be the issue

Comment: What does the documentation say? Sending secret API key via GET-request is not a good idea from my point of view.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked if your API-Key is valid? Or perhaps if you wrote a letter wrong.

Comment: Yes, my API-KEY is valid. the letters are right.